# harmonic function in a 2d disc.

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

So my professor gave as the following question: Given the function u which is continuous in $\bar{D}$ , where $D = \left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x^{2}+y^{2}<1 \right \}$, and harmonic in $D$.

Find $u(0,0)$, if $u(x,y)=x^{2}y^{2}$ for $(x,y) \in \partial D$.

Now I know from the mean value theorem that the value of $u$ at the center of the disc is the mean of its values at the border of the disc $\partial D $. So we get $u(0,0)=\frac{1}{\left | \partial D \right |} \int_{(x,y) \in \partial D} u(x,y)ds$, but how do we calculate this?
Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: i thought of using Poissons $u(\rho ,\theta )=\frac{1-\rho ^{2}}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{2\pi }\frac{f(\theta )}{1-2\rho cos(\varphi -\theta )+\rho ^{2}}d\theta $ with $x=\rho cos\theta ,y=\rho sin\theta $ but it seems to only make things worse when it comes to calculating a number. I used complex numbers and found  $u(0,0)=\frac{(1-\rho ^{4})\rho ^{2}}{8}$ which does not seem to be the answer we are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u(0,0)= \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}u( \cos t, \sin t) dt=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2 t \sin^2 t dt.$$

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try.